# Errors with Skyline Tool ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, error-999999

I am trying to run the Skyline tool, with the aim of using it to produce a skyline graph for a point. I have a DSM and a point dataset both in the same projected coordinate system. I got the error 050013 which suggests that there was an error decoding the feature layer. I readded the DSM terrain raster but I now get the error 999999.

To try and get around this I didn't assign an input surface so it could use a virtual one but then I get the output as shown in the image where they are just circles. Has anyone had any problems with this tool or can think of anything I may be doing wrong?

[image]